# What does that code snippet signify "tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)" in tensorflow code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have seen many usage of that line of code in many tensorflow projects. What does the line do in tensorflow?

Comment: What have you investigated so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logging level [documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging/set_verbosity) basically tells you:
If you set it to the level as displayed (`INFO`), then TensorFlow will tell you all messages that have the label `INFO` (or more critical).

Say you would only be interested in `WARN` or `ERROR`, then you could similarly set `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.WARN)`

Comment: If I don't use tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.WARN) then also tensorflow shows the error message. Then what is the necessity of specifying that line? @dennlinger

Comment: Exactly, since it shows `WARN` _or worse_. Yet, you would not see any `INFO` messages anymore.

Answer (score 7):

It is easier to try this yourself. I use Pycharm IDE and it captures the output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)
#tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO) 
# Other settings

tf.logging.debug('Debug')
tf.logging.info('info')
tf.logging.warn('warn')
tf.logging.error('error')
tf.logging.fatal('fatal')
```